# Why code shows that strings are the same when one string is greater than the other

Tags: c, string

I wrote a function that replaces the function `strcmp()`.
The cases are:

**1**) strings are the same
**2**) second string will come first in the dictionary.
**3**) first string will come first in the dictionary.

In theory:

> '*a*' > '*b*'

So '*a*' is the first string to come in the dictionary, however, my code doesn't exactly view it like this, instead it treats it like it's case 1.

Here is my code:

```
int cmp(char fString[], char sString[])
{
    int flag = 0;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; fString[i]; i++) {
        if (fString[i] == sString[i]) {
            flag = 0;
        } else
        if (fString[i] > sString[i]) {
            flag = 1;
        } else {
            flag = -1;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

The conditions are:

```
if (cmp(fString, sString) == 0) {
    printf("Strings are the same.\n");
} else
if (cmp(fString, sString) > 0) {
    printf("First string will come first in the dictionary\n");
} else {
    printf("Second string will come first in the dictionary\n");
}
```

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I properly compare strings in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c)

Comment: You shouldn't iterate over anything beyond the first character when comparing `"aardvark"` and `"zanzibar"`. Also -- what happens when `fString` is longer than `sString`? In that case `sString[i]` will eventually be out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you must try to handle this problem , the length of both Strings are equal ? if not you , must work with minimum

notice that your implemented `cmp` function only works when the strings are equal

here is the problem of your `cmp` function , you must `break` your `for` loop when you know one String is **bigger** or **less** than other string , but your code continues checking remaining characters :

```
for(i = 0; fString[i]; i++)
    if(fString[i] == sString[i])
        flag = 0;
    else if(fString[i] > sString[i]){
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }else{
        flag = -1;
        break;
    }
```

if i was you , first i assume the strings are equal , then i would try to change the flag if String is greater than or less than other string

```
int flag = 0 , i = 0;
for(i = 0; fString[i]; i++)
        if(fString[i] > sString[i]){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }else{
            flag = -1;
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is false: 'a' > 'b' should instead read

> 'a' < 'b'

If you insist on writing a function that returns `1` if the first string argument should come before the second argument, you should at least implement the correct algorithm:

- you must stop the iteration when you encounter characters that differ. You currently keep looping and overwrite `flag` with the value for the next character.
- you must deal with the case where the first string is shorter than the second, you currently return `0`, which is incorrect.

Here is a corrected version:

```
int cmp(char fString[], char sString[]) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; fString[i]; i++) {
        if (fString[i] == sString[i]) {
            continue;
        } else
        if (fString[i] > sString[i]) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    if (sString[i])
        return 1;  // fString is shorter, it should come first 
    else
        return 0;  // strings are the same
}
```

Note however that it is very confusing to use counter-intuitive conventions. A string comparison function should return `< 0` is its first argument is conceptually less the the second and should come first in a list sorted by increasing order.

Note also that the `strcmp()` function compares the strings according to the order of the type `unsigned char` instead of `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is wrong, you should return the difference between the characters when it's not `0` instead. Because the `flag` is overwritten if the last characters are the same, something very easy to happen if you include a trailing `'\n'` in your strings.

Note that by last I mean, the last character of the shortest string is the same as that of the longer string at the given position.

One quick fix is to check for `flag == 0` in the `for` loop condition, but you can simply check if the difference between the two characters is `0` and continue with the next character or return **it** if it's not 0.